# Шаблон проектирования, который позволяет выполнять отложенное обновление

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, архитектура

Существует ли какой-нибудь шаблон проектирования, который позволил бы производить отложенное обновление объекта?

Другими словами, я хочу выполнять обновление объекта, только при использовании его публичных методов. Конечно, в каждый метод добавлять функцию обновления не хочется, учитывая что у меня используется целая иерархия объектов (ведь они добавляют тоже свои публичные методы)

Comment: Есть, как минимум, рефлексия, с помощью которой можно узнать какое поле: приватное, защищенное или публичное... Соответственно можно какому-то управляющему классу/методу скармливать объект, в котором смотреть у объекта при помощи рефлексии, если публичный метод , то делать что хотите

Comment: Что-то совсем не хочется использовать рефлексию, мне кажется это слишком неизящное решение

Comment: А что значит "отложенное обновление"? В чем оно заключается? Приведите живой пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: @andreycha, простой пример это использование представления, у которого изменилась модель (в целях производительности, модель не может заниматься ведомлением о своих изменениях)

Comment: Если используемый язык/рантайм поддерживает аспектно-ориентированное програмирование - можно создать средствами AOP динамический Proxy, который будет оборачивать все public-методы.

Comment: А почему тогда не отказаться вовсе от внутреннего состояния, и на всех запросах к объекту лезть в модель?

Comment: @Nofate, это хороший паттерн, но что делать, если у меня существует иерархия объектов, к которым нужно применять отложенное обновление? создавать иерархию своих прокси?

Comment: @AlexAkel, да но это можно сделать полуавтоматически кодогенерацией во время исполнения (если, конечно, язык позволяет)

Comment: @Nofate, очень большая нагрузка получается

Comment: @VladD, проблема в том, что придется добавлять методы в во все публичные методы

Comment: @AlexAkel, нагрузка на что?

Comment: @AlexAkel: Непонятно. Приведите пример кода лучше.

Comment: @VlaD, да именно это я и хотел сказать - придется добавлять методы во все публичные методы.

Comment: @Nofate, нагрузка на время исполнения программы. Я как полагаю, вы хотите в рантайме создавать proxy на каждый вызов публичного метода (через рефлексию)

Comment: Не на каждый вызов. А только на каждый экземпляр.

Comment: @Nofate, все равно большая нагрузка получится из-за рефлексии

Comment: Обычно AOP используют там, где можно один раз сгенерировать и все. Т.е кол-во объектов не меняется.

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал примерно такую реализацию.
Пусть у нас есть класс, обновление которого занимает много времени (просто присвоить объект проще сразу и не мудрить). Например нам нужно перевычислить много значений, зависящих от состояния объекта. Если предполагается частые обновления, но редкий доступ к недовычисленным полям, то можно делать как-то так.

```
class {
       private boolean isNeedRecalc;
       private Object field;
       private Object someInnerState;
       public updateObject(Object newObject){
            isNeedRecalc = true;
            someInnerState = newObject;
            /*.... */ 
       }

       private updateField(){
            isNeedRecalc = false;
            /* ... */
       }

       public Object getField(){
            if (isNeedRecalc)
                updateField();
             return field;
       }
}
```

Флаг может быть как 1 на весь класс, так и для каждого поля.

Comment: А что делать, если у нас есть иерархия объектов с такой логикой?

Comment: @AlexAkel это чуть абстрактный вопрос, каждый объект по идеи так должен себя вести ну или только нижний. Проблем в целом не будет.

Comment: дело в том, что я ведь могу использовать публичные методы у наследников (которых в базовом классе нет), тогда придется вспомогательный метод добавлять в каждый новый публичный метод потомка

Comment: это слишком общий вопрос, если можете приведите пример кода, иначе сами понимаете, каждый паттерн индивидуально применяется, нет золотых пуль